# Azure Purview unable to add a second DB from the same server

Tags: database, azure, azure-purview

I am unable to register a second Azure SQL database in Azure Purview. These two databases are in the same Azure Server. Please see Image 1 and Image 2.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had repro’d and was able to add another database in the same SQL server by doing these steps:

- Once we go to the Source option in the data map, we must select this New scan option as mentioned in the above image.

[image]

- Then you will get another window where we can select the database we need to add.

[image]